# YAFU for factorizing extremely large numbers

Tags: factorization

I installed Yafu on my computer (Windows 10), but it doesn't work. Is it due to the fact that Yafu is incompatible with Windows 10 or have I to install something else?

Answer (score 1):

There is a YAFU forum at https://www.mersenneforum.org under "Factoring Projects." It is best to ask for help there.

"It doesn't work" is an insufficient description of your problem. You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GUI version of YAFU software which works with Windows 10 from my open-source project: http://qurancode.com

Just click the **Yellow PI** icon to launch PrimeCalculator :)

[image: QuranCode v7.29.139]
[image: PrimeCalculator]
[image: PrimeCalculator]